# Converting a self subquery to a self join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery

I was wondering if there was a way to convert a self subquery to a self join 
Here is the self subquery

```
SELECT a, 
       b 
FROM   c AS t1 
WHERE  ( b IN (SELECT b 
               FROM   c AS t2 
               WHERE  ( t1.b = b ) 
                      AND ( t1.e <> e )) )
```

Comment: What is your subquery even doing?  It seems like you could just get rid of it...

Comment: It checks to see if something in the table has the same value of b

Comment: and e is a primary key used to differentiate between things

Comment: `SELECT a,b FROM c WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM c c2 WHERE c2.b=c.b AND c2.e<>c.e)` probably would  be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to find the duplicates an `EXIST` would probably be faster:

```
SELECT a,b FROM c WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM c c2 WHERE c2.b=c.b AND c2.e<>c.e)
```

If you want to join every record with its duplicate but get only one record for each:

```
select  t1.a
,       t1.b
,       t1.e as t1e
,       t2.e as t2e
from    c as t1
inner join c as t2
on      t1.b = t2.b 
        and t1.e > t2.e
```

(note that i've used `>` instead of `<>`)

Comment: `IN` and `EXISTS` will probably give the same plan.

Answer (score 2):

As `e` is the Primary Key another way of approaching this would be

```
SELECT a, 
       b 
FROM   (SELECT a, 
               b, 
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b) AS Cnt 
        FROM   c) T1 
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.b
FROM c as t1
join c as t2 on t1.b=t2.b
WHERE t1.e <> t2.e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  t1.a
,       t1.b
from    c as t1
join    c as t2
on      t1.b = t2.b 
        and t1.e <> t2.e
```