# Doing self join to hide duplicates - getting error message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Ok, I'm doing a self query to suppress duplicates for a view. The code I'm using is:

```
    USE BILLING

    SELECT Provider_Code,
           Provider_LName,
           Provider_Fname,
           Provider_Title,
           AGENCY_LOCATION_NAME_LINE_1,
           CostCenter_AbbrName
    FROM   dbo.ServiceProfiler prov1
           INNER JOIN
           dbo.ServiceProfiler prov2
           ON prov1.Provider_Code = prov2.Provider_Code
    WHERE  0 = (SELECT COUNT(s1.Provider_Code)
                FROM   prov1
                WHERE  prov2.Provider_Code = prov1.Provider_Code
                       AND prov2.Provider_Code < prov1.Provider_Code);
```

When executing the query on SQL Server 2005 I get the message:

> *Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Invalid object name 'prov1'.*

I cannot for the life of me understand why the alias names are invalid. I think I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762390/converting-a-self-subquery-to-a-self-join). But it's very generic and doesn't show a full 'real' query using the aliases.

Comment: Remove the where and test. Most likely you cannot reference prov1 in the sub query.

Comment: And the sub query is messed up.  You test for both = and < and it can't be both.

Comment: I've answered your query as asked (you can, but I can't work out what you are trying to acheive. Please can you explain what you are actually trying to acheive, perhaps with example input/output?

Comment: The subquery is _supposed_ to suppress duplicates in a single table.

Comment: you can't call the `prov1` table inside the `select` of the `where` statement

Comment: @rbartlejr I understand that - but I don't understand **why** there are duplicates in the table? What makes them duplicates? Why can you not use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates? Why can you not refine your outer `SELECT` to prevent duplicates in the first place? Please edit the question to explain more about what data you will be holding

Comment: @RB Because while the first three columns are the same the last three of the select may have different data. None of these columns are the PK. So you'll get rows like: 1. 1, doe, john, admin, tampa, agency1 2: 1, doe, john, case manager, agency2

Comment: @rbartlejr  You STILL have not defined what you want.   Do you want the unique values for the first three column?  Then for the last 3 what:  Max, min, min, first, random?

Comment: @Blam I want unique rows based on Provider_Code.

Comment: @rbartlejr And you STILL have not defined what you want. OK unique  Provider_Code.  If Provider_Code = A appears 5 times with 5 different values for Provider_LName what do you want for Provider_LName?

Comment: @Blam The first 3 columns will always be the same since Provider_ID is always exactly associated with the FName and LName (hence the reason for them always the same. What I wanted to do was weed out the duplicates caused by columns 4 through 6 having mixed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something more like this:

```
SELECT Provider_Code,
           Provider_LName,
           Provider_Fname,
           Provider_Title,
           AGENCY_LOCATION_NAME_LINE_1,
           CostCenter_AbbrName
FROM   dbo.ServiceProfiler prov,
     (SELECT Provider_Code,count(*) Count from dbo.ServiceProfiler group by Provider_Code HAVING count(*)=0) q
WHERE prov.Provider_Code = q.Provider_Code
```

You could also do a straight up sub-select, I'd imagine. I think joining on a subquery is easier to understand, but that's me.

Comment: I think you are missing a join and the list of Provider_Code with a count() = 0 will be empty

Comment: @Blam Actually (with a small tweak) it worked perfectly! I just needed to make the HAVING count(*)=0 to HAVING count(*)<=1. Thanks Norman!!

Comment: I'm doing an implicit join. Indeed, I meant to have it =1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `FROM prov1` - there is no table called `prov1`. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx), FROM is used with a *table_source*, which is a table or view name.

You **can** reference `prov1` from the where clause of your subquery however.

Note also that your where clause in your subquery does not make sense. `prov2.ProviderCode` cannot be simultaneously less-than **AND** equal-to `prov1.ProviderCode`.

Comment: Gotcha fixed the first part and attempted to fix the second part but that throws more errors. I'll have to research it a bit more I guess. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM   prov1
```

here is your problem; since is another `select`, you need to specify the `table` where you `select from`.
You can use the `alias` `prov1` in the where's of that `select`, to `join`, but need to specify the `table`, and also, a new alias.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call the `prov1` table inside the `select` of the `where` statement, you have to call `ServiceProfiler AS Prov3` and  change the Where Statement as @RB Said

> Note also that your where clause in your subquery does not make sense.
>   prov2.ProviderCode cannot be simultaneously less-than AND equal-to
>   prov1.ProviderCode.

for it to work